# Add into a List from Object Type Json Data in wpf C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Hello I have Problem to add into a List of JSON data. My Json Data as follows . I got this Data From a API.

```
["1.DCM",
"2.dcm",
"3.dcm",
"4.dcm"]
```

as I have not find any object so First I think I can  add to list without deserializing . But Latter I thought I will make into a object type then I will Add . So I did This Here is My code .

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            string alldicomfile = responseString;
            object allDicom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
        }
```

I get in allDicom variable  this
`{["1.DCM", "2.dcm", "3.dcm", "4.dcm"]}`
But this is Invalid Json . So I think I have to use alldicomfile  but How to Add this in List . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deserializing to a list:

```
var allDicom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseString);
```

Then you can add to it:

```
allDicom.Add("5.dcm");
```

Then you can serialize it back in to JSON:

```
responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allDicom);
```